# Why doesn't my for loop work when trying to fill a datatable

Tags: c#

I have code for filling my `DataColumn`s. but the for loop I created wont work.
The first `DataTable` is being filled with a SQL query. The second `DataTable` needs to be partially being filled with data from the first `DataTable`. So I built a second `DataTable` manually with a for loop to fill it, but it doesn't work?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class _Planning : System.Web.UI.Page
{
ConnectionStringSettings Leerstoftabel;
SqlConnection connection;
int cursusID = 2;
DataTable LeerstofTabel;
DataTable Planning;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Leerstoftabel = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CursusPlanner"];
connection = new SqlConnection(Leerstoftabel.ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cursus.naam AS [Cursus Naam], vak.vaknaam, cursusvak.volgnummer, les.dagnummer, les.hoofdstuknummer, les.naam AS [Les Naam], les.lesomschrijving FROM cursus INNER JOIN cursusvak ON cursus.cursusID = cursusvak.cursusID INNER JOIN vak ON cursusvak.vakID = vak.vakID INNER JOIN les ON vak.vakID = les.vakID WHERE(cursus.cursusID = @cursusID)ORDER BY cursusvak.volgnummer";

//int cursusID = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cursusID", SqlDbType.Int, 0).Value = cursusID;

connection.Open();

//het creeëren van een datatabel
DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
LeerstofTabel = new DataTable();
LeerstofTabel.Load(rdr);

connection.Close();
}


protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
// weekend days can't be selected in calendar
if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//create the DataTable named "Planning"
Planning = new DataTable ("Planning");

//Add the DataColumn using defaults
DataColumn datum = new DataColumn("Datum");
datum.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
datum.AllowDBNull = false;
datum.Caption = "Datum";
Planning.Columns.Add(datum);

//Add the DataColumn using defaults
DataColumn hoofdstuk = new DataColumn("Hoofdstuk");
hoofdstuk.AllowDBNull = false;
hoofdstuk.Caption = "Hoofdstuk";
Planning.Columns.Add(hoofdstuk);

//Add the DataColumn using defaults
DataColumn omschrijving = new DataColumn("Omschrijving");
omschrijving.AllowDBNull = false;
hoofdstuk.Caption = "Omschrijving";
Planning.Columns.Add(omschrijving);

//Add the DataColumn using defaults
DataColumn lessen = new DataColumn("Lessen");
lessen.AllowDBNull = false;
lessen.Caption = "Lessen";
Planning.Columns.Add(lessen);


for (int i = 0; i < LeerstofTabel.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (LeerstofTabel ["vaknaam"]).ToString() != vorigvak  // this statement doesn't work
    {
        DataRow newplannning = Planning.NewRow();
        newplannning["Datum"] = "";
        newplannning["Hoofdstuk"] = "*" + LeerstofTabel["vaknaam"];
        newplannning["Omschrijving"] = "";
        newplannning["Lessen"] = "";
        Planning.Rows.Add(newplannning);

    }

    Vorigvak = (LeerstofTabel["vaknaam"])ToString();
}


GridView1.DataSource = Planning;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What's your error? What do you mean it won't work?

Comment: on the If (LeerstofTabel ["vaknaam"]).toString 1= vorigvak i get the error : Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: too long code, you need just to post which code cause issue

Comment: @user1782391 So what are you trying to do?  A datatable doesn't have an indexer.  Were you trying to access the `i`th row?  If so, it would be: `LeerstofTabel.Rows[i]["vaknaam"]`.  If you want to access something else, you'll need to explain *what*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If vaknaam is your column name, you'll need to use it on a row

```
var r = LeerstofTabel.Rows[i]
if (r["vaknaam"]).ToString() != vorigvak) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly sorry if this is wrong. It's quite hard to understand your code due to the language.

```
 if (LeerstofTabel ["vaknaam"]).ToString() != vorigvak
```

should be

```
 if (LeerstofTabel.Rows[i]["vaknaam"]).ToString() != vorigvak
```